# When working with websockets should I open a new websocket connection for every different task? Or should I do everything within one connection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I work with socket.io in my react app, and I have a back-end expressJS server. My question is, should I open a new websocket connection for every functionality separately, or should I use just one connection for multiple things? Like for example I have a chat component where users can send chat messages between one another, but I also want to make a web socket for notifications listener and online status. I wonder wether not to open new connections for that and keep things separate or just to have one connection (this would hopefully save server recourses) and make different calls to that connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO has the concept of [namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/) which you can use to differentiate different aspects of your application.

Internally, it will actually share a WebSocket (assuming it isn't using HTTP long-polling) for all namespaces.

There's otherwise nothing wrong with a new WebSocket, besides having your server to perform more work, since there's another socket to handle and keep track of.

Comment: So maybe I will do everything within one connection then. I see that namespaces work like rooms, that I already use in my chat, so I will use different 'emits' for different tasks.
Thanks for the anwser!

Comment: @ms3300 The documentation I linked already showcases that by using `io.of('/namespace')`, you basically have a completely separate "socket IO", except it uses multiplexing. (and you can't use namespaces within namespaces, far as I know?). Don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as the solution.

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks for the help again!